# Can I search Facebook checkin deals?

Tags: facebook, checkin

Is there a way that allows searching the deals available in the checkin deals?

I have found APIs that allow adding deals programatically, but not searching deals.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook hasn't published official checkin deal API's yet, although according to [this](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/07/12/check-in-deals-api/) article they are in private beta testing with certain locations.  But as of now there is no api for programmatically searching deals.

The [check-in deals search page](https://www.facebook.com/deals/checkin/) doesn't require authentication so you could watch the ajax url it calls with Chrome debugger tools network tab and scape the results.  This will most likely be in violation of their terms of service though.

Comment: This question is about Checkin Deals, which are not being phased out with Deals. - I'm not sure of the answer to the OPs question, but just wanted to clarify that they're asking about a currently supported produce

Comment: @Igy you are correct. They annouced Places and Deals are dead, but checkin deals are still alive for now.  I updated my answer.